# Converting an <audio> tags track time into Mins:Secs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I created a frankensteined audio player, and need a little help with the track timing. I have it now so it counts from 0 -> whatever the track time is, in seconds. I can't seem to figure out how to convert those seconds into mins:secs.

I'm new to timing/converting with JS, so any help is appreciated!

HTML

```
    <audio src="" id="player" 
        ontimeupdate="document.getElementById('tracktime').innerHTML = Math.floor(this.currentTime) + ' ' + Math.floor(this.duration);">\
</audio> 

    <span id="tracktime">0  0:00</span>
```

**CODE UPDATE**

Alright, so I now have it so it just shows minutes as a single digit (ie: 1:00 = 1, 2:00 = 2, 3:00=3, etc)

I need it to show it as 3 digits, ie: 1:00 = 1:00, 2:00 = 2:00, etc.

**Here is my current audio tag:**

```
<audio src="http://dosh.dk/bb/track.mp3" id="player" ontimeupdate="document.getElementById('tracktime').innerHTML = Math.floor(this.currentTime / 60) + ' ' + Math.floor(this.duration / 60);">
    <script>
      var minutes = Math.floor(time / 60);

      var seconds = time - minutes * 60;

      var hours = Math.floor(time / 3600);
time = time - hours * 3600;

      function str_pad_left(string,pad,length) {
    return (new Array(length+1).join(pad)+string).slice(-length);
}
      </script>

    </audio>
```

I just can't seem to concatenate the seconds onto the minutes.

Comment: Math.floor(this.currentTime / 60) + ' ' + Math.floor(this.currentTime % 60)

Comment: That ended up making my left side (the counting one) stay static at 0, and my right side (the total time) count up (updated my question to show current code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out, just had to reformat somethings..

**HTML**

```
<div class="scrub-bar">
      <div class="progress"></div>
      <div class="time current">0:00</div>
      <div class="time duration">0:00</div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
//var audio = link to my audio file    
audioplayer.addEventListener("ended", replay, false);
    audioplayer.addEventListener("timeupdate", timeUpdate, false);

    function reskinTime(secs, format) {
            var hr = Math.floor(secs / 3600);
            var min = Math.floor((secs - (hr * 3600)) / 60);
            var sec = Math.floor(secs - (hr * 3600) - (min * 60));
            if (sec < 10) {
                    sec = "0" + sec;
            }
            return min + ':' + sec;
    }

    function timeUpdate() {
            playPercent = (audioplayer.currentTime / duration) * 100;
            playhead.style.width = playPercent + "%";
            timer.innerHTML = reskinTime(audioplayer.currentTime.toString());
    }
```

Comment: No need to calculate hours first, just use: var min = Math.floor((secs % 3600) / 60); var sec = Math.floor(secs % 60);

Answer (score 0):

In CMS Effcore we have applied the following simple and ingenious solution:

```
function formatTime(time) {
  var h =        Math.floor(time /    3600);
  var m = ('0' + Math.floor(time / 60 % 60)).slice(-2);
  var s = ('0' + Math.floor(time      % 60)).slice(-2);
  return h + ':' + m + ':' + s;
}
```